# MySQL transfer from backups

Tags: mysql, backup-restoration, database-restore

I had a server die and I have been trying to restore the data onto a new server. I had a mysql database.

I have all the files stored in /var/lib/mysql. Each database had a database privileges associated with itself and one other database. This way, each site had it's own configuration to connect only to their database.

When trying to recover the database, I seem to have lost all the privileges granted on the databases except for the root user. Is there something I am missing or will I need to recreate all of the privileges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may sound a little risky but here it goes

If you have a physical backup copy of the following:

- `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/user.frm`
- `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/user.MYD`
- `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/user.MYI`

copy them back to /var/lib/mysql/mysql, then `service mysql restart`

Since each user had specific database privileges, you must restore

- `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/db.frm`
- `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/db.MYD`
- `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/db.MYI`

Comment: I can see the users in the user table of the mysql database now. However, it seems like all the privileges have been reset. When I go to a database and look at its privileges, it does not show anything. Each database user is supposed to have specific privileges for its own database.

Comment: Updated my answer...

Comment: I missed the part about db.frm, db.myd, and db.myi. It is all working now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check you restored `/var/lib/mysql/mysql`. If that's corrupt, the data is gone I'm afraid.

Comment: +1 for zeroing in on `/var/lib/mysql/mysql` first